# Not able to read data send by controller on jsp

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to send data on jsp from my controller and trying to read it with Spring EL but i am not able to do it.

Controller:

```
 @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String StudentHome(RedirectAttributes ra){
        String msg="mydata";
        ra.addFlashAttribute("msg", msg);
        return "home";
 }
```

jsp:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    ${msg}
</body>
</html>
```

Do i need to include anything else?

Comment: Have you added @Controller annotation to the class?

Comment: Yes, i have @Controller annotation for class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RedirectAttribute is only used when you redirect. Try using `return "redirect:home";`
-BCP

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the `@Controller` annotation above the `@RequestMapping` annotation
2. Make a bean for your controller in `controller-spring-beans.xml`.

**Sample**

```
<bean name="yourController"

    class="your.package">

    <property name="successView" value="path/to/your.jsp" />

</bean>
```

Read about `Spring` [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.m3/reference/html/creating-bean-definitions.html)

Comment: i have @Controller annotation for class.

Comment: Did you add the bean like I included?

Comment: No i haven't. If i am using annotations then what is use of creating bean. Can u please tell me abt it bcoz i don't know.