# Spring Redirct to a new Page From Ajax Calling

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring

Hi My Problem is when I try to redirect a page In  Spring Controller Insted of returning to new Page it Return to The response of the calling Browser.

```
@RequestMapping(value="grandTicketDetail",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView grandTicketDetail(@RequestParam("refernceId") String refernceId,ModelAndView model){
    //model.addAttribute("refernceId", refernceId);
    model.addObject("refernceId", refernceId);
    model.setViewName("view/secure/grandTicketDetail");
    //return "view/secure/grandTicketDetail";
    return model;

}
```

Now this code generate exception Invalid target for Validator
I  previously try with return type string But It return as a response.

How to do ?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="grandTicketDetail",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String grandTicketDetail(@RequestParam("refernceId") String refernceId,ModelAndView model){
    return "redirect:view/secure/grandTicketDetail";
}
```

Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19249049/how-to-pass-parameters-to-redirect-page-in-spring-mvc) and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22812604/not-able-to-read-data-send-by-controller-on-jsp/)

Comment: I think redirect will work.Bot that alling change ajax to form submit.